# Syncing my work on laptop and main computer?

Tags: version-control, synchronization

If there was a single project, the task would be easy - I could have just put it under a VCS and be done.

But I have a lot of those projects (some of which are under version control, come are not), which I want all to be in sync. For simplicity's sake, I can say that they are all placed in a single directory, new projects are added sometimes, old ones are deleted, etc.

I'm running Ubuntu on both systems.

What is the best way to keep my work in sync?

Comment: if you can access one computer from another - rsync

Comment: @Qwe - but with rsync, I would have to sync everything manually and remember to make sync everytime I get home. And if I will edit a file on both systems (by mistake), there would be some problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://one.ubuntu.com/ or something else cloudy ;) you can if you want also set up an own cloud with for example OwnCloud(you can mount to local folders http://owncloud.org/support/webdav/)

If you in the future have everything in a vcs you can push to for example github/bitbucket or your own server.

Comment: One bit about that WebDAV - would I be able to edit the files in the mounted directory if my laptop is not connected to the internet (sometimes) and thus cannot reach the server?

Comment: I do not now, have not tried it, but it depend on the client. They are talking about an offline client for OwnCloud http://owncloud.com/blog/open-source-file-sync-and-share-project-adds-cloud-text-editing-and-more but I do not found it live yet.